# What should I flag link-only answers as?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, flagging

When voting to delete an answer in the review queue there is an option

> **link only (and not spam)**

However, there is no such option when actually flagging answers.  When flagging link-only answers I usually use either

> **not an answer**
>   This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

or

> **in need of moderator intervention**

so I can add an explanation.  I usually just put something like "Link only."  Both of these have been picked up and resulted in the answer being deleted.  But for the sake of consistency, what should I really tag such answers?

Comment: Relevant MSE Discussion - [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use to flag using the custom reason with something as simple as "*Link only answer.*"
As a mod now, that would be great.

Just so you know among the three general flag types:

- #### not an answer
- #### very low quality
- #### in need of moderator intervention

which of those you use does not make much of a difference. Those three are all handled the same way by us mods.

However, **spam** and **rude or abusive** have special meaning. These two should only be used when something is [spam or offensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/278094). These have more "power" than a normal flag. For example after 6 spam or offensive flags not only is the post deleted and locked, but the author will loose 100 rep.

Comment: I've noticed the community bot doing things (such as downvoting) when flags are marked as helpful. Not sure if it does different things with different initial flag types, but it might?

Comment: @gandalf3 The DV comes when a VLQ flag is marked helpful.